# Comparing SQL date without current month

Tags: sql, ms-access, date-math

I have a table in Access with string columns and a date column. I want to get all the rows from the table when the date is lower than 22.10.2010, except this month. So, i need the rows from 30.09.2010 to ...

I tied something, but I figured out it's not right:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE YEAR(date)<=2010 AND MONTH(date)<10
```

But this solution it's not good, and i have no other idea. Could you help me with a general solution, pls?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zeroth day of a month is the last day of the previous month:

```
DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),0)
```

Therefore:

```
 SELECT [name] FROM [table] 
 WHERE [date]<=DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),0)
```

Comment: This is a very good solution, and elegant too, thank you very much, it's working, but I have to try mangokun's solution too, it seems stunningly simple ad I think it could work too. Thanks again!

Comment: Just bear in mind that mangokun's solution is not sargable: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Answer (score 1):

### Access?

String together the year, month, and "1" (to get the first day of the month of `date`) and convert that to a `Date`.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   dateColumn 
           < CDate(CStr(YEAR(date)) + "-" + CStr(MONTH(date)) + "-1")
```

### SQL

Subtract the `DAY` (minus one) from the date in question from the date to get the first of the month. Then return all rows less than this value.

```
DECLARE @date DATE
SET @date = GETDATE()DECLARE

SELECT  *
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   dateColumn 
           < DATEADD(DAY, -( DATEPART(DAY, @date) - 1 ), @date)
```

Comment: I'm not in sql server, Iso I tried this: SELECT * FROM  MyTable
WHERE dateColumn < (DATEADD(DAY(d), -( DATEPART(DAY(d), d) - 1 ), d)), where d is 22-10-2010, and it's telling me: "This expression is typed incorrectly, or is too complex to be evaluated"

Comment: @DaJackal, this may not be of much help since I don't have Access readily available, but see if you can get it to work for you.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT name FROM table WHERE ( YEAR(date)<2010 ) OR ( YEAR(date)=2010 AND MONTH(date)<10 )

Comment: That can't use the indexes, so will perform very poorly on a data set of any size.

Answer (score 0):

you subtract the number of days in the month so far and use that date for the comparison

```
Select myName FROM myTable Where myTable.myDate <=DateAdd("d",-Day(Now()),Now());
```

The above query will give you all the records till the end of the last day of the last month.

Cheers.

Comment: Is there some affirmative reason why you're using Now() instead of Date()? Nobody mentioned anything other than dates, and Now() returns a date and time component, and won't necessarily give you the right results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT you_col
  FROM YourTable
 WHERE your_date 
          < DATEADD('M', 
              DATEDIFF('M', #1990-01-01 00:00:00#, NOW()
          ), #1990-01-01 00:00:00#);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below functions can be used. These even work for leap years.

'If you pass #2016/01/20# you get #2016/01/31#

```
Public Function GetLastDate(tempDate As Date) As Date
    GetLastDate = DateSerial(Year(tempDate), Month(tempDate) + 1, 0)
End Function
```

'If you pass #2016/01/20# you get 31

```
Public Function GetLastDay(tempDate As Date) As Integer
    GetLastDay = Day(DateSerial(Year(tempDate), Month(tempDate) + 1, 0))
End Function
```